# How to read from different sheets in a spreadsheet using gid value. Google sheets API

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I am using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) to read data from a spreadsheet, but that spreadsheet has many sheets inside it. And I could not find a way to specify which sheet I have to read from, using the `gid` value in the link of the spreadsheet.

My code which retrieves data is:

```
ValueRange result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
```

In the above `get()` method there is an argument for `spreadsheetId`, but not for `sheetId`. How can I specify the sheet I want to retrieve data from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `range` parameter is a string using A1 notation, so you include the sheet *name* there. [(Sheets API Reference.)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

For example, if the sheet name is "Sheet5" and you want range "D1:F8", then that line would read

```
ValueRange result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, "Sheet5!D1:F8").execute();
```